# JavaScript: how to append paragraph if situation is not filled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, for-loop, if-statement

I'm working on a simple project that checks to see if a student is working on an online journal. The student's progress is checked with a userId. If the student's userId does not appear in the JSON returned by an API call to the class API, a paragraph should be appended to a container to tell the student they have not completed anything.

Here's an example of the type of data I'm working with.

```
data = [ 
    { "userId": 101, "pagesDone": "005" },
    { "userId": 102, "pagesDone": "010" },
    { "userId": 103, "pagesDone": "020"},
    { "userId": 104, "pagesDone": "015" }
]
```

Now let's say that I'm working with a student with a userId of 106. This student doesn't appear in the JSON data because they haven't started working on the journal.

```
let currentUserId = 106;
// Student has not completed anything in their journal

let showStudentJournal = (data, currentUserId) => {

  for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
    if (currentUserId == data[index].userId) {

  // I have figured out the code here, basically I append a progressBar to a container to show the student's progress
  // I won't show the code here since that's not what we're focusing on. 

      //The thing I want to happen is, get a paragraph to appear if the student hasn't filled out any of the online journal yet
    } else {
      $("#progressContainer").append('<p>You have not yet started your online Journal</p>');
    }
  }
}
```

However, the function ends up running 4 times (because there are 4 students in the data). So this is what I get back:

```
'<p>You have not yet started your online Journal</p>'
'<p>You have not yet started your online Journal</p>'
'<p>You have not yet started your online Journal</p>'
'<p>You have not yet started your online Journal</p>'
```

How do I get the error message to only appear once?

Comment: Use a flag to know whether the user id is available in the array and depending on the flag add your append statement outside of the for loop.

Comment: Instead of using `for` loop use `find`. If no `userid` was present then append paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

use `find`

```js
const currentUserId = 005;

const data = [ 
    {"userId": 101, pagesDone: "005"},
    {"userId": 102, pagesDone: "010"},
    {"userId": 103, pagesDone: "020"},
    {"userId": 104, pagesDone: "015"} 
];

let showStudentJournal = function(currId) {
    const found = data.find(({userId}) => parseInt(currId) === parseInt(userId));
    if(found) {
        // code
    } else {
        $("#progressContainer").append('<p>You have not yet started your online Journal</p>');
    }
}

showStudentJournal(currentUserId);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progressContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let currentUserId = 106;
//student has not completed anything in their journal

let showStudentJournal = (data, currentUserId) => {
    let userFound = 0;
    for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
        if (currentUserId == data[index].userId) {
            userFound = 0;
            //I have figured out the code here, basically I append a progressBar to a container to show the student's progress
            //I won't show the code here since that's not what we're focusing on. 

            //the thing I want to happen is, get a paragraph to appear if the student hasn't filled out any of the online journal yet
        } else {
            userFound = 1;                
        }
        if (userFound == 1) {
            $("#progressContainer").append('<p>You have not yet started your online Journal</p>');
        }
    }
}
```

I have only add the variable before the for loop and assigned `0` to it and in your loop just change this variable to `0` in your `if` condition and `1` in your `else` condition.

Once the loop finishes, just check value if it is `1` then show the error. In this you doesn't need to change your code much.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` condition should be `!=` instead of `==`.

If you wanted to **show the progress bar for students with `userId` that is not equal to 106**(`currentUserId`), then the condition is supposed to be `currentUserId != data[index].userId`.

**EDIT:**

> However, the function ends up running 4 times (because there are 4 students in the data). So this is what I get back:

This is **not because there are 4 elements**  in the array. This is because the **4 elements does not meet the condition** of having a `userId` that is equal to `currentUserId`. Hence, going to the `else` scope.